# Angular 9 app returns data but Chrome console displays the below error

Tags: angular, api

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'fName' of undefined

The data gets displayed properly but the error still shows in the Chrome browser console. I have tried the Elvis operator but same result.

Controller Code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.api.getEmploye().subscribe((data: Employee) => {
console.log(data);
this.employee = data;
});


HTML Code

<div class="form-group">
<label for="fName">First Name</label>
<input
type="text"
class="form-control"
id="fName"
required
[(ngModel)]="employee.fName"
name="fName"
/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="lName">Last Name</label>
<input
type="text"
class="form-control"
id="lName"
[(ngModel)]="employee.lName"
/>
</div>
```

Comment: This happens because the response comes after the view has rendered. This employee should have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because you need to initialize the variable to be distinct than undefined.

Remember that angular is re-rendering every time the data changes and you're performing an api request (async action) so "employee" doesn't have a value when the component is initialized and the template it's looking for some values on ngModel (fName), that's why it prints an error.

Then, when the api returns the data and you store it in the component, the template updates with the correct values.

If you dont' want to initialize the employee you can use async pipe in your template, here's the docs for that https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: employee: Employee = {
    id: 0,
    fName: '',
    lName: '',
    email: '',
    ssn: '',
  };

Comment: Solved by initializing as above

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` so that the DOM gets rendered when the data is available, example:

```
<div *ngIf="employee"
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    id="fName"
    required
    [(ngModel)]="employee.fName"
    name="fName"
  />
</div>
```